# SHAP with an imblearn pipeline

Tags: python, shap, imblearn

How can I use SHAP after using `imblearn` pipeline? This is my code:

```
pipeline_adaboost = Pipeline([('smt', SMOTE(random_state=42)),
                    ('adaboost', AdaBoostClassifier(random_state=42))])

adaboost_parameters = {"adaboost__n_estimators":[int(x) for x in np.linspace(30, 100, 20)],
                       "adaboost__learning_rate":[float(x) for x in np.linspace(0.0001, 1, 20)],
                       "adaboost__algorithm":['SAMME.R','SAMME']}

tuned_adaboost = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline_adaboost, adaboost_parameters, cv = 5,
                                  random_state=42,
                                  n_jobs=-1, scoring='roc_auc')
tuned_adaboost.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Shap code:

```
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(tuned_adaboost.best_estimator_)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], X_test)
```

Error result :

```
Model type not yet supported by TreeExplainer: <class 'imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline'>
```

Comment: Still no solution for this problem?
I also want to use a model (including pipelines to transform the data) as the input for shap.

Comment: The big question is: why use SMOTE?